# Best way to send 10GB vector across network in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am curious to know what the best way to send 10 GB once over the network in Haskell? I don't want to send it as binary without having to write a decode/encoder. Is it best to keep it strict or lazy?

Comment: as a lazy bytestring, i think. Just as supposed by the network package and the file api.

Comment: You might want to look at [Data.Conduit.Network](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra/docs/Data-Conduit-Network.html).

Comment: Oh that is a really nice package. I'll look into it. Thx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use Pipes. A zlib compressed network example can be:

```
module Main where
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import Pipes.Network.TCP
import Data.ByteString
import Pipes.ByteString as PB
import System.Environment
import Pipes.Zlib
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

myReceive :: (MonadIO m) => m ()
myReceive = serve (Host "127.0.0.1") "8000" $ \(sock, remote) -> do
  Prelude.putStrLn $ "TCP connection established from " ++ show remote
  runEffect $ decompress defaultWindowBits (fromSocket sock 4096) >-> PB.stdout

mySend :: IO ()
mySend = connect "127.0.0.1" "8000" $ \(sock, remote) -> do
  Prelude.putStrLn $ "Connection established to " ++ show remote
  runEffect $ compress bestCompression defaultWindowBits (PB.stdin) >-> toSocket sock

main = do
  a:[] <- getArgs
  case a of
    "send"    -> mySend
    "receive" -> myReceive
    _ -> Prelude.putStrLn "Usage: netsend <send|receive>"
```